# How can I configure webpack to use original variable names?

Tags: webpack

This is what my webpack usually ends up with at the moment:

[image]

As you can see, I have a lot of these "_data_profile_js__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__" variables in there. Is there any way I can configure webpack to use the original variable name instead of this?

I can see why it does that, but it just decreases the readability by a lot...

Comment: Why would you do that? If you want to inspect your code, generate a sourceMap?

Comment: How would I go about doing something like this?

Comment: Search the [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/).